# Raspistill and C

Tags: c, image-processing, raspberry-pi

We're doing a project in school where we need to do basic image processing. What we want to do in our project is take a picture every 50ms with our Raspberry Pi and do real time image processing.

We've tried to include raspistill in our c-program but so far nothing has worked. The goal of our project is to design a RC-car which follows a blue/red/whatever coloured line with help from image processing.

We thought it would be a good idea to make a c-program which does all image processing necessary, but we currently struggle with the idea of bringing recorded images into the C program. Is there a way to do this with raspistill or should we try a different way?

Thanks in advance,
anthrx.

Comment: You could maybe try `RaspiCam` with or without `OpenCV` which would be the natural way to approach machine vision... http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

Comment: @MarkSetchell isn't that a c++ library though? We're trying to keep it C if that's possible, or would be c++ be essential in our scenario?

Comment: I don't know of any pure `C` version, but I have been wrong before and am happy to be shown to be wrong again - so let's wait and see if any other bright spark can educate us both:-) I shall keep an eye out too. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hey Mark, we've decided to use the suggested library, but I am currently struggling with the download of the library. I downloaded the  .zip from the website but now I'm unsure what to do, sorry if it seems like such an easy thing to do but it just doesn't work for me.